# Two Select elements(drop downs) with one conditional options

Tags: html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-hooks, html-select

I was using two select elements (Drop Down). The first one is for *item*, and the second one is for *color*.
The *color* is dependent on the value of *item*.

If the value of *item* is **ITEM1** then *color* can have **color1, color2, color3** and If the value of *item* is **ITEM2** then *color* can have **color4,color5,color6**. The code is below

```
 <select name="item" onChange={changeItem}>
    <option value="ITEM1"> Item1 </option>
    <option value="ITEM2"> Item2 </option>
  </select>
  <select name="color" onChange={changeInputs}>
    {inputs.item === "ITEM1" ? (
      <Fragment>
        <option selected value="color1">Color 1</option>
        <option value="Color2"> Color 2 </option>
        <option value="Color3"> Color 3 </option>
      </Fragment>
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        <option selected value="color4">Color 4 </option>
        <option value="Color5"> Color 5 </option>
        <option value="Color6"> Color 6 </option>
      </Fragment>
    )}
  </select>
```

When I change the value of *item*, I manually update the value of *color* to the first option of their respective *color*.

But here comes an issue. When I change the *color* option to **color 2**(without changing *item* i.e., *item* is still **ITEM1** ) and then changes the value of *item* to **ITEM2**, the initial value shows in *color* option is **color 5** (not **color4** as I was expecting the default value of the option should be there) which creates a bug in my web app. How to resolve it? Or there is another way to do the same. THANK YOU in advance.

You can simulate the above [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-hopper-d2ucy?file=/src/App.js:733-1536)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I think it's because you don't use the `keys` in your options. So you can write like this

```
          <Fragment>
            <option selected key="color1" value="color1">
              Color 1
            </option>
            <option key="Color2" value="Color2">
              Color 2
            </option>
            <option key="Color3" value="Color3">
            </option>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <option selected key="color4" value="color4">
              Color 4
            </option>
            <option key="Color5" value="Color5">
              Color 5
            </option>
            <option key="Color6" value="Color6">
              Color 6
            </option>
          </Fragment>
```